# How can I create a single dictionary out of a dictionaries within a dictionary with some different and similar keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary having two key values, and each key refers to a value that is a dictionary itself. Now my concern is to extract the key values of the values regardless of their first key. And these two values have keys that are same as well as different.

I need to get a single dictionary where the different keys remains same, while the keys that are same in both dictionary , so there value updates i.e they add up.

```
with open('report.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data['behavior']['apistats'])
```

The output consists of this:

```
{
    "2740": {
        "NtDuplicateObject": 2,
        "NtOpenSection": 1,
        "GetSystemWindowsDirectoryW": 23,
        "NtQueryValueKey": 32,
        "NtClose": 427,
        "NtOpenMutant": 2,
        "RegCloseKey": 8
    },
    "3908": {
        "RegCreateKeyExW": 2,
        "GetNativeSystemInfo": 1,
        "NtOpenSection": 1,
        "CoUninitialize": 6,
        "RegCloseKey": 27,
        "GetSystemInfo": 1,
        "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot": 180,
        "UnhookWindowsHookEx": 2,
        "GetSystemWindowsDirectoryW": 6,
        "NtQueryValueKey": 6,
        "NtClose": 427
    }
}
```

But I need a single dictionary where the same `'apistats'` value adds up as a new value and the keys don't repeat, regardless of parent keys `'2740'` and `'3908'`.

Comment: its print(data['behavior']['apistats'])

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Please start your code by making a direct assignment to `data`; you don't seem to have trouble with the input, so skip past that in your post.

Comment: Basically it sounds like you would like to merge sub-dictionaries, so it would also be very helpful for you to show what the desired output should be — since the rules you state for merging are somewhat vague and don't cover every possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with `groupby`:

```
input_dict = {
    "2740": {
        "NtDuplicateObject": 2,
        "NtOpenSection": 1,
        "GetSystemWindowsDirectoryW": 23,
        "NtQueryValueKey": 32,
        "NtClose": 427,
        "NtOpenMutant": 2,
        "RegCloseKey": 8,
    },
    "3908": {
        "RegCreateKeyExW": 2,
        "GetNativeSystemInfo": 1,
        "NtOpenSection": 1,
        "CoUninitialize": 6,
        "RegCloseKey": 27,
        "GetSystemInfo": 1,
        "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot": 180,
        "UnhookWindowsHookEx": 2,
        "GetSystemWindowsDirectoryW": 6,
        "NtQueryValueKey": 6,
        "NtClose": 427,
    },
}

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

refactored_items = ((k2, v2) for v1 in input_dict.values() for k2, v2 in v1.items())
sorted_refactored_items = sorted(refactored_items, key=itemgetter(0))
res = {k: sum(i for _, i in g) for k, g in groupby(sorted_refactored_items, key=itemgetter(0))}
```

res:

```
{'CoUninitialize': 6,
 'CreateToolhelp32Snapshot': 180,
 'GetNativeSystemInfo': 1,
 'GetSystemInfo': 1,
 'GetSystemWindowsDirectoryW': 29,
 'NtClose': 854,
 'NtDuplicateObject': 2,
 'NtOpenMutant': 2,
 'NtOpenSection': 2,
 'NtQueryValueKey': 38,
 'RegCloseKey': 35,
 'RegCreateKeyExW': 2,
 'UnhookWindowsHookEx': 2}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, can you just brief me whats actually happening in refactored items line please and the next one

Comment: @SidraNisar refactored items can get all `apistats, value` pairs, the sorted one is sorting the pairs by the `apistats`, and then it can be grouped by `groupby`.